# Entry point for test suite with multiple files in Cabal project?

Tags: haskell, testing, cabal, cabal-install

New to Cabal, so sorry if this is obvious, but I obviously want to have more than one file in my Cabal project's test suite, yet the `.cabal` file is insisting on being given an entrypoint. What do I put for this?

For example, if I have two modules in my library and want to test each in their own test file. One is no more important than the other, so how do I go about making one of the files an entrypoint?

Comment: Make a simple `Main` file that does nothing but run both of the module-tests? Is that the _obvious answer_ you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make two test suites.

```
test-suite A
    main-is: test-module-A.hs

test-suite B
    main-is: test-module-B.hs
```

Or you could make a single suite that imports both test modules.

```
test-suite both
    main-is: test-both.hs
    other-modules: TestA, TestB
```